# myArray[diffinday] = dayCount not working correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I need to save the values from a calculation I'm doing 121 times. I was able to find code that was able to save values inside a for loop, but it isn't working correctly, and I don't know why. Here's my code.

```
 int[] myArray = new int[121];

        //how to read how many bdays? = 121 bdays!
        for(int x=0; x < 121; x++){

            String[] bdaynames = {database.readWord(),database.readWord(),database.readWord(),database.readWord(),database.readWord()};
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bdaynames));

            //we get a arraylist

                for(int diffinday = 0; diffinday < 121; diffinday++){
                    bmonth = Integer.parseInt(bdaynames[2]);
                    bday = Integer.parseInt(bdaynames[3]);
                    byear = Integer.parseInt(bdaynames[4]);
                    LocalDate start = new LocalDate(year,month,day);
                    LocalDate end = new LocalDate(year,bmonth,bday);
                    int dayCount = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
                    //System.out.print(dayCount+" ");
                    myArray[diffinday] = dayCount;
                    if(diffinday == 120){
                        System.out.print("THIS IS THE ONE!): "+Arrays.toString(myArray));
                    }
            }
```

It keeps on printing out like this (small portion of code)

```
THIS IS THE ONE!: [-200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200, -200]
THIS IS THE ONE!: [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12]
THIS IS THE ONE!: [-102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102, -102]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, because it should be all in one array becuase of the if statement clearly saying I want the array only when it reaches to 121. It also needs to be in one array, so I can sort it out correctly. It

Comment: Whats the difference between your outer and inner loop?

Comment: I need to read a .txt file 121 times (it has 121 dates). Do I need it?

Comment: Why do you need **two nested loops** even if you're reading 121 times?

Comment: Thank you so much. I got rid of the for loop.... THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: It works now. The for loop caused all the weird stuff to happen.

Comment: Please close/delete the question if you think its solved by a way that wouldn't help anyone possibly in future.
This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you have two for loops, one for x (i dont see x being used anywhere) and one for diffinday.

Can you perhaps just use one for loop, something like

```
   for(int x=0; x < 121; x++){

        String[] bdaynames = {database.readWord(),database.readWord(),database.readWord(),database.readWord(),database.readWord()};
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bdaynames));

        //we get a arraylist
            bmonth = Integer.parseInt(bdaynames[2]);
            bday = Integer.parseInt(bdaynames[3]);
            byear = Integer.parseInt(bdaynames[4]);
            LocalDate start = new LocalDate(year,month,day);
            LocalDate end = new LocalDate(year,bmonth,bday);
            int dayCount = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
                //System.out.print(dayCount+" ");
            myArray[x] = dayCount;
            if(x == 120){
                    System.out.print("THIS IS THE ONE!): "+Arrays.toString(myArray));
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see wrong right away is
LocalDate end = new LocalDate(year,bmonth,bday); should be
LocalDate end = new LocalDate(byear,bmonth,bday);

Also you are counting but nothing is changing, everything is a fixed variable. If you want to iterate through your bday names you will need to put it in the second for loop. I'm not even sure why you have a nested for loop, should be able to be done in one.